# How to modify web address in localhost using wamp?

Tags: windows, localhost, wampserver

How to change localhost/sample/index.php to dev.sample.com? I make it in ubuntu using nginx I wonder how to make it in windows using wamp server.

Comment: Here is a post that should help you create the proper requirements for setting up Virtual hosts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add this line:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.sample.com
```

To `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (edit with notepad).

After that, uncomment the line (around line number 512):

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Of `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apacheX.Y.Z\conf\httpd.conf` by removing the inital `#`, so you get:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Finally, edit `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apacheX.Y.Z\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` by adding this to the end of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/YOURPROJECTPATH/sample"
    ServerName dev.sample.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The `apacheX.Y.Z` stands for the Apache version your WAMP is using.

You can check more examples on [how to create virtual hosts in the Apache's docs examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) (WAMP = Windows+**Apache**+MySQL+PHP).

Once you're done with these edits, left click the WAMP icon near the window's clock, go to *Apache > Service > Restart Service* and you can now use the new URL. A minor suggestion: you can choose more uncommon URLs, e.g. `sample.developer` so you don't end up on a real website when Apache service is down.

### For keeping the http://localhost/ redirection

You can leave two lines in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 dev.sample.com
```

Or you can use the same line for this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost dev.sample.com
```

However, I suggest that you don't pile up many references in one line (4 to 5 should be ok). It's preferable to have more lines to the same IP.

Along with your new site's virtual host, you can also have this in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apacheX.Y.Z\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` (above or below the other):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works great but when I try to go localhost it said now 404 Not Found

Comment: Sorry lack of rep. Thanks a lot